# Changing $live_site in configuration.php has no effect in Joomla 3

Tags: php, joomla

I have developed a completely new site, on a new server for "www.mysite.it", but I want maintain access to the old one developed in Joomla 3.3.

I have created a "old.mysite.it" subdomain pointing to the old IP address and changed "www.mysite.it" and "mysite.it" domains in DNS panel to point to the new IP address.

Finally, I have changed `$live_site` entry in `configuration.php`:

`public $live_site = 'http://old.mysite.it';`.

When I try to access http://old.mysite.it I get Apache message, "Site in construction".

What's wrong?

Note that the old site is working. If I change hosts file on my local computer I can reach it on "www.mysite.it".

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have an `index.html` file in the root of your old site, preventing index.php from ever being reached.
Additionally, please consider changing other configuration parameters:

- tmp and log paths;
- database name, username, password

and don't forget to look into the `.htaccess` for any custom redirects which may no longer apply.